# Recommended way to format numbers in a locale aware way?

Tags: java, android

Lets assume we have one million.

In English it should be formatted as `1,000,000` in German it should be `1.000.000`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Using [NumberFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class:

For English:

```
NumberFormat nf_us = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
String number_us = nf_us.format(1000000);
```

For German:

```
NumberFormat nf_ge = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
String number_ge = nf_ge.format(1000000);
```

Comment: The first example is not for english but for the United-States.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [NumberFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html).

Android documentation is quite clear on it.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this with using the [NumberFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class, this also allows you to parse Strings into a local aware number.

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
String localeFormattedNumber = formatter.format(1000000);
```