# Android, get US locale value from ES locale number

Tags: java, android, locale

My App contains number in ES format for ES locale. 
But while handling the number I need its US equivalent, so that I can proceed with my logic. For example, My number is 25000, its (Locale.US) equivalent is (25000.00)

In (Locale.ES) it is displayed as (25.000,00)

Now if I want the  US format number from 25000,00 how do I do the conversion. Someone help me in this context, where conversion is done from one locale to another.

Edit: After displaying the number in edittext, when I retrieve it using gettext() I get 25.000,00 as the string. And when I apply int conversion it comes out as just 25, where its actual values is 25000.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4375470/2649012

Comment: @Der Golem I saw that sir, but once i display a number i dont have a hold of it. I only have the displayed format, so i need to convert it from that format. How do I do it?

Comment: **A number is a number**. In every locale, the number is the very same. OR do you want it's **String representation** (which is NOT a number)?

Comment: 25000 in spanish is displayed as 25.000,00, if i use gettext() and apply int conversion this is read as 25 in english sir, that is my problem

Comment: Yes, **DISPLAYED**. But the number **per se** is the same. And it's **not 25** in English (it's UNIVERSAL, it's not divided by 1000). So what you want is the **string representation** of a number (which is a string, so you can't do math on it)?

Comment: Ok i think i confused you sir. The string i retrieve from textbox is 25.000,00. So when i use int conversion it returns 25 as output. How to get the actual value?

Comment: Sir, replace the "." with "". So to correctly get 25000

Comment: @Der Golem I really thank you sir, for trying to help me. And sorry that i confused you. I found the possible solution from AlexR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you have to parse the number using `ES` locale and format it using `US` locale:

```
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("es", "ES")).parse("25000,00"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir, thats exactly something i was looking for. You saved my day.