# Cost Matrix in Java

Tags: java, weka

I need to implement the Cost  Matrix in Java Eclipse editor using the Weka API. I have imported all the Weka API in Jave and using the code:-

```
public class EvaluteCM {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
 CostMatrix matrix = new CostMatrix(
                       new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:/data.txt")));
 System.out.println(matrix);
 }
}
```

and I show here some of my data in text file data.txt

```
0.211429    0.223573    0.274898    0.260206    0   class1
0.211429    0.223573    0.274898    0.260206    0   class1
0.099854    0.110879    0.312785    0.291716    0   class1
0.747867    0   0.272726    0.320873    0.727273    class2
0.775455    0   0.272726    0.304774    0.727273    class2
0.775455    0   0.272726    0.304774    0.727273    class2
0.76761 0   0.272726    0.304774    0.727273    class2
```

when I implement the class EvaluteCM, I got the following error

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0.211429"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at weka.classifiers.CostMatrix.<init>(CostMatrix.java:524)
at EvaluteCM.main(EvaluteCM.java:13)
```

Any Help will be appreciated?

Comment: Could you post the *full* stacktrace? IMHO `throws Exception` in main is pretty awful.

Comment: We don't know what's inside CostMatrix

Comment: The CostMatrix is import from Weka API as below                               import weka.classifiers.CostMatrix;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving your data file as CostMatrix. CostMatrix file should be like below, taken from [weka wiki](http://weka.wikispaces.com/CostSensitiveClassifier). See [Cost Matrix](http://weka.wikispaces.com/CostMatrix) Weka Wiki. It gives better example as matlab file

**Format of the cost matrices**:

regular

```
 % Rows    Columns
 2    2
 % Matrix elements
 0.0    5.0
 1.0    0.0
```

Matlab single-line format

```
 [0.0 5.0; 1.0 0.0]
```

Comment: Dear Atilla Ozgur; I know the pattern for the Cost Matrrix but what is the format of the file input to accept the implementation. I mean, is it my Data ok to implement this matrix. Please let me have your comments

Comment: Did you try to change your data to arff file?

Comment: Yes, I have converted to filename.arff but I got the error also with Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "@relation"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)

Comment: This is most certainly locale problem. Your numbers are not formatted according to your locale. Look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375410/recommended-way-to-format-numbers-in-a-locale-aware-way

Comment: I have used the standard filename.arff from the Weka URL http://weka.wikispaces.com/file/view/AirPollution.arff/383151680/AirPollution.arff and the same problem still exist. I mean the problem in not related with numbers locale problem. Please advise

Comment: Do you know which line in CostMatrix is throwing this exception? I found that that my problem was because the cost matrix file had a white space in the beginning of each line.