# Java.Locale Ireland

Tags: java, locale, currency

I'm trying to format currency in a java application, so I've written a CurrencyFormatter. I'm trying to format in the form €123,456,789.00, and this works locally but when I deploy to my company server, the variables are shown as $123,456,789.00

Here is my code:

```
 import java.text.NumberFormat;
 import java.util.Locale;

 public class CurrencyFormatter {
     private static final Log log = Log.getLog(CurrencyFormatter.class);

     public static String getEuroFormat(Double num) {
     log.info("Formatting: " + num + " to euros");
     Locale ireland = new Locale("en","IE");
     NumberFormat irelandFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(ireland);
     return  irelandFormat.format(num);
   }
}
```

Any advice on how to resolve my issue would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you got the locale wrong, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375410/recommended-way-to-format-numbers-in-a-locale-aware-way

Comment: It works if you use `Locale.UK` in `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.UK);` ?

Comment: The problem is its an Irish application, that needs to display in euros, not a UK application displaying in pound.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks right to me. My guess would be that the en_IE locale is missing on the server. You can check which locales are supported by a call to `NumberFormat.getAvailableLocales()`.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, I wasn't able to add this locale to the server, so I developed the following workaround to resolve my issue.

```
 import java.text.DecimalFormat;
 import java.text.NumberFormat;
 import java.util.Locale;

    public class CurrencyFormatter{
      public static String getEuroFormat(Double num){
            String pattern="\u20ac###,###.##";
            DecimalFormat euroFormatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
            String output = euroFormatter.format(num);
            return output;
      }
    }
```

Instead of trying (and failing) to use Locale, I implemented a formatter by creating a patter (above), and passing this pattern through to a DecimalFormat object. I then used this to format my input.